# Can string.format sequence appear in any order

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I have a string here,

```
return  string.Format("/abcXYZ990099/abc.aspx?IDA={0}&Name={1}&Teacher={2}",
                ID, Name, Teacher);
```

Now because of requirement changed I need to get "abcXYZ990099" from database too, Is it possible to do something like this,

```
return  string.Format("/{3}/abc.aspx?IDA={0}&Name={1}&Teacher={2}",
                    ID, Name, Teacher, NewPropertyValue);
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this ?

Comment: Surely it makes more sense to have: `string.Format("/{0}/abc.aspx?IDA={1}&Name={2}&Teacher={3}".....`  ....since `0` comes before `3`? Makes logical sense that way, when you read it left to right.

Comment: @V4Vendetta I remember trying it months ago and it didn't worked(I assume so **not sure**), hence i asked question as if it's right way of doing or not, change your display name to "positive" might help you :)

Comment: @user13814 The question mentions nothing on why it didn't work or any issue encountered, for the display name it is very much "positive" (Had it been different would it have implied a different meaning :) )

Comment: @V4Vendetta I have got my answer, thanks for positive assistance :)

Comment: The order of the placeholders does not matter, as long as the index is present in the suffixed parameter array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. But I'd re-index the place holders and re-order the params to suit the order they should appear in the returned string, e.g.

```
return  string.Format("/{0}/abc.aspx?IDA={1}&Name={2}&Teacher={3}",
                    NewPropertyValue, ID, Name, Teacher);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly OK, format items can appear in any order in the string.

For example, when format strings are stored as localized resources, the format items might be in a culture-specific order.  For example, to display a full name, you could use:

```
String.Format(Resources.FullNameFormatString, firstName, middleName, lastName)
```

And the display order might depend on the culture, e.g.:

```
en-US: "{0} {1} {2}"  // First Middle Last

fr-FR: "{2}, {0} {1}" // Last, First Middle
```

You might even have a localized version that doesn't use one of the format items (e.g. middle name):

```
"{2), {0}" // Last, First (middle name not used)
```

Of course, in your example it probably makes more sense to reorder the items, as others have said.

Answer (score 0):

You can do. But change the order, since the code must be understandable.

```
string.Format("/{0}/abc.aspx?IDA={1}&Name={2}&Teacher={3}",NewPropertyValue, ID, Name, Teacher);
```